# how to use solr cloud efficiently for up to 1000 collections?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

is there any way so that we can use solr cloud to run 1000's of collections efficiently?
Now we are running 300 collections on solr cloud but because of this solr is eating lots of heap memory and solr shut's down unknowingly.
And as the collections increases solr is taking lots of time to start.
is there any way to do this?

Comment: Which version of Solr? How are your collections structured? Replicated and sharded to a low number of servers, how many servers in total?

Comment: we have single server with 2 nodes. and each collection has replicationFactor 1 and numShards also 1.